# Are there advantages of using sklearn KMeans versus SciPy kmeans?

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

From the documentation of [sklearn KMeans](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)

> class sklearn.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=8, init='k-means++',
>   n_init=10, max_iter=300, tol=0.0001, precompute_distances='auto',
>   verbose=0, random_state=None, copy_x=True, n_jobs=1)

and [SciPy kmeans](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.vq.html)

> scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans(obs, k_or_guess, iter=20, thresh=1e-05,
>   check_finite=True)

it is clear the number of parameters differ and perhaps more of them are available for sklearn.

Have any of you tried one versus the other and would you have a preference for using one of them in a classification problem?

Comment: Without trying it, i would always prefer sklearn. Better documentation (including user-guides) and much more tools you would likely use too, like Cross-Validation/Gridsearch. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: The scipy implementation gives you the option to set your own centroids, which can be nice. Also note that for most applications, you'll be wanting to use [kmeans2](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans2.html), not the one you quote. Besides that, I can't say.

Answer (score 5):

**Benchmark**.

And you will never touch the scipy one again.

Comment: it seems difficult to compare one to another -- the params for SciPy do not match perfectly those for sklearn: for example, the default number of initializations for sklearn is n=10, while in SciPy it isn't explicit. Using 100 centroids for both and other params as default, SciPy is faster but that doesn't mean better.

Comment: Disable all the extras. `n_init=1`, `tol=thresh=0`, `max_iter=iter=100000` (you want the final result, not an interim result). Use a *large* data set.

Comment: Scipy has less overhead. A major advantage when running on small datasets.